# How can I debug PHP Laravel on Visual Studio Code without use XAMPP or WAMP server

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm using PHP 7.3.1 with Laravel 5.7.

How can I proceed to debug step by step without install a external server?
Using Xdebug?

Just running with the command:

```
php artisan serve
```

All solution then I founded use WAMP.

Answer (score 4):

Setup xdebug extension in php.ini file as per your PHP version.

Check which version of xdebug support your PHP here : https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Don't forget to change your xdebug extension path `zend_extension`.

Add xdebug extension into the browser also. For mozila click [here.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/)

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "C:\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0-7.2-vc15.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
;xdebug.remote_log = "c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
;xdebug.remote_port = 9000
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;36000 = 10h
;xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Comment: where can I find php.ini if i'm using laravel? i'm not install php. i'm just install laravel project from console with the command "laravel new my-web-site"

Comment: You can find php.ini file where you've installed PHP. If you are using windows then check into the C:/PHP or C:/Program Files

Check this link : https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 2):

I'd try starting artisan with Xdebug like `php -z /path/to/xdebug.so artisan serve`.

And then use the [PHP debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug) extension for Visual Studio code, to set breakpoints, inspect variables and all other debugging stuff.

Comment: where can i find xdebug.so? on the website just have xdebug.dll

Comment: Oh, you're using Windows! Then it should be xdebug.dll instead. You can ahead and try to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `launch.json` file within the `.vscode` directory of the project with the following contents did the trick for me:

```
{
     // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
     // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
     // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
             "name": "Listen for XDebug",
             "type": "php",
             "request": "launch",
             "port": 9000
         }

     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finished setting up development environment, and would like to list some notes:

- using Homestead/Vagrant/VirtualBox virtual environment and VSCode PHP Debug plugin
- edit `.vscode/launch.json`, or after first <kbd>F5</kbd> will be created with settings like here:

  ```json
     //file: .vscode/launch.json
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
          "type": "php",
          "request": "launch",
          "port": 9003
      },
     // ...
  ```
- ```sh
   # sudo vim /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini # symlink
   # or sudo vim /etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini
   zend_extension=xdebug.so
   xdebug.mode = debug
   xdebug.discover_client_host = true
   xdebug.client_port = 9003
   xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
   xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
   xdebug.start_with_request=yes
   xdebug.client_host=10.0.2.15 # <--- my Homestead/Vagrant/VirtualBox IP address (ip addr show)
  ```
- `sudo service php8.1-fpm restart`
- `php artisan serve` - will deploy/publish/attach php code to `php8.1-fpm` service
- [image]

### Notes about development environment

- Host OS is `Ubuntu 21.10`
- Have installed VirtualBox and Vagrant
- Homestead cloned and started - `vagrant up`
- `vagrant ssh-config` copy paste to `~/.ssh/config`
- VSCode extensions

  - Remote - SSH
  - Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files
- Using VSCode extension *Laravel Extension Pack* collection

### Additional notes:

- there are two parts of Laravel/PHP that could be debugged:
- `php artisan serve` - running from shell to deploy/publish/attach php files to `php8.1-fpm`

  - one way to debug that launching part is to use this command line:

    ```sh
    php \            
      -dzend_extension=xdebug.so \
      -dxdebug.mode=debug \
      -dxdebug.discover_client_host=true \
      -dxdebug.client_port=9003 \
      -dxdebug.max_nesting_level=512 \
      -dxdebug.idekey=VSCODE \
      -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes \
      -dxdebug.client_host=10.0.2.15 \
      artisan serve
    ```
  - place brake-point somewhere at `artisan` script in root folder
  - do not need that part at all (just mentioning here for sake of completeness) and could be replaced with `php artisan serve`
- `service php8.1-fpm status` - running in background

  - to debug that part, `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` file should be configured like here:

    ```sh
    zend_extension=xdebug.so
    xdebug.mode = debug
    xdebug.discover_client_host = true
    xdebug.client_port = 9003
    xdebug.max_nesting_level = 512
    xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes
    xdebug.client_host=10.0.2.15
    ```
  - always do `sudo service php8.1-fpm restart` after changing `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini`
  - place brake-point somewhere in `SomeCustomController.php` file
- keep running IDE debugger (client) with <kbd>F5</kbd> from `./vscode/launch.json` and php *parts* from above will be able communicate with it over port `9003`
- Laravel docs:

  > ... consider using Laravel Homestead
- Xdebug docs:

  > There could be more than one `php.ini` file. In many set-ups there is a different one for the command line (often `cli/php.ini`) and the web server (often `fpm/php.ini`)

### Helper commands to check if Xdebug extensions are set:

- `php-fpm8.1 -m` - Xdebug should be listed
- `php --ini` and `php -v` - Xdebug not listed